# Disallow direct access while allowing ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I use this code to disallow direct access to php file

```
if (__FILE__ == $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']){
  die("Direct access forbidden");
}
```

My problem is I need to call the php this way

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getverse.php",true);
```

it also return `Direct access forbidden` error.

How can I allow this call to php file while disallowing direct access to it from a browser?

Thanks

Comment: You can establish some sort of authentication protocol, but ultimately an HTTP request is an HTTP request. If your site responds to ajax (HTTP) requests, it can be fooled into responding to a request from any HTTP client on the internet.

Comment: Consider what you're trying to do... You want to allow access while simultaneously disallowing access.  Time to reconsider the problem you're trying to solve.  Does the user have access to this service or not?  What are you actually trying to prevent the user from doing and why?

Comment: @David, I think I already mentioned the different scenario. `xmlhttp.open("GET","getverse.php",true);` is being called from a javascript file which I want to allow. Direct access to a php file from a browser address bar is the one that should not be allowed. I was hoping there is some ways to make these 2 different from a technical stand point and disallow the direct browser access

Comment: @Wayne: But *why*?  What are you trying to prevent?  Consider the underlying goal, not the current attempted implementation.  What is that goal?  There’s a pretty good chance that the attempt isn’t the right way to achieve that goal.  But you’re not asking about the goal, you’re asking about the attempt.

Comment: @David, I think I get your point. Thanks. That is a freaking good point.

Comment: @David, just to close this, the goal is simply not to allow direct access to php file from a browser address bar. an answer below meet that goal and accepted as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am not sure its just a single PHP file or you are using any Framework or a CMS.

But you can try,

```
if (__FILE__ == $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] && !isset($_GET['ajax'])){
  die("Direct access forbidden");
}
```

Invoke this file using

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getverse.php?ajax=1",true);
```

Comment: This is not secure at all, I can add ?ajax=1 in browser and get the file

Comment: for my current purpose, this serves me well. I will accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

`if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {...}`

but remember you can spoof any header with cURL anyway:

`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("X-Requested-With : XMLHttpRequest"));`

(but at least it should take care of accessing the PHP file directly in the browser).